# Symfony2 Doctrine Native SQL Query The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I am having problem fetching data by using doctrine with native sql, below code works fine on my local development machine but when I test it online. I get

> Oops! An Error Occurred The server returned a "500 Internal Server
>   Error". Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] and let us
>   know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as
>   soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

**Here is my query in controller:-**

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$connection = $em->getConnection();    
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM students");  
$statement->execute( );
$results = $statement->fetchAll();

return $this->render('MobileLearnerBundle:Default:test_page.html.twig', array('results'=>$results));
```

**test_page.html.twig code:-**

```
{% for item in results %}

   {{ item.first_name }}

{{ item.last_name }}

{% endfor %}
```

Thanks for the help in advance !

Comment: What do your logs say?

Comment: [2014-08-30 09:32:59] request.INFO: Matched route "mobile_learner_loginpage_customlogin" (parameters: "_controller": "Mobile\LearnerBundle\Controller\LoginPageController::CustomLoginAction", "_route": "mobile_learner_loginpage_customlogin") [] []

Comment: [2014-08-30 09:32:59] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception PDOException: "SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" at /var/www/html/mobile/m/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php line 40 {"exception":"[object] (PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) at /var/www/html/mobile/m/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:40)"} []

Comment: But My password is correct, 

{ parameters: { database_driver: pdo_mysql, database_host: 127.0.0.1, database_port: null, database_name: symfony, database_user: root, database_password: MyPWD, mailer_transport: smtp, mailer_host: 127.0.0.1, mailer_user: null, mailer_password: null, locale: en, secret: ergegfdgfgfa7c095060d0887c675c2df1456bfb, debug_toolbar: true, debug_redirects: false, use_assetic_controller: true, database_path: null } }

Comment: Does it work if you change the `database_host` to localhost?

Comment: No I tried changing it to localhost and my ip as well

Answer (score 0):

I think I was putting in the wrong password but now when I put in the right password I get

```
Invalid type for path "doctrine.dbal.connections.default.password". Expected scalar, but got object
```

by running below command in my linux server

```
php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```

Reason behind is that I have @my_password@ and when I remove " @ " from password no error but obviously then its not correct password. Is doctrine telling me that it does not allow "@" at the beginning and end of a password. I tried both ways @my_password@ and '@my_password@'